# Layout of my app is ruined when call or hotspot status bar is appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout, autolayout

I have faced a problem while testing my app, everything was perfectly running until I turn on the personal hotspot and the blue bar is appear on the top, all the labels and buttons are moved downward:

[image]

The code of `viewDidLoad` is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    day1Times = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    day2Times = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    day3Times = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    day4Times = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    day5Times = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    day6Times = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    day7Times = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self performSelector:@selector(sendTokenIDSelector) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getTimes) withObject:nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];
   
}
```

The constraints configuration is as following:

[image]

How can I fix their location and keep making it not move regardless of the status bar?

Comment: Can you show us your codes, especially `viewDidLoad()` ?

Comment: Where and how is your background image added?

Comment: Make sure your autoresize masks are set correctly, and you can test this within the simulator by pressing Cmd+T

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Please find the code in the question, I have just added it

Comment: @MikeWeller as an UIImage, is there is any better way to do it? I am a bit new in this field :)

Comment: @WDUK I have tried this "autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | ..." but it still not working

Comment: If your image has the correct frame and autoresizing mask, it should shift down with everything else.

Comment: You mention in the comments below that you have autolayout turned on. Can you show the contraints that are configured in Interface Builder?

Comment: @SixtenOtto please check the constraints configuration in the latest edit of the question

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to your views autoresizing mask.You should hook them to the edges so that they won't stretch when the notification occurs.

Open the size inspector using Tools -> Size Inspector or Command+3.

Make sure the strut for the top margin is enabled (indicated by the solid red lines). Thus you can make sure to have the constant margin even when the superview changes.

Comment: I have forgot to mention that I am enabling the autolayout so there are no solid red lines to play with